# Consume XML - message undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

I'm trying to consume XML Web Service but I'm getting result.Message undefined in  success function. Whats wrong in this code?  The error is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Message' of undefined
```

Here is my code:

```js
function RequestService() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://www.brazilmachinery.com/Arquivos/RSS/pt-BR/12.xml",
        data: "",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(data) { SucessCallback(data.d); },
        error: function(data) { FailureCallBack(data); }
    });
}

function SucessCallback(result) {
    $('p').html('Resultado: ' + result.Message + ' <br /> Descrição: ' + result.Description);
}

function FailureCallBack(result) {
    alert("erro");
}
```

Comment: The `result` object does not have a `Message` property. Without seeing the actual response we can't really be of any more help. Are you certain you want to provide `data.d` to `SuccessCallbac()` and not just `data`?

Comment: with data instead of data.d I don't get error but get undefined string

Answer (score 0):

Your response is an XML file. You are assuming it returns JSON object and trying to access a property.

You will have to parse the XML file and extract the node you want to retrieve. Below is a XML to JSON utility function. You can use this to access the property.

```
function xmlToJson(xml) {   
    // Create the return object
    var obj = {};

if (xml.nodeType == 1) { // element
    // do attributes
    if (xml.attributes.length > 0) {
    obj["@attributes"] = {};
        for (var j = 0; j < xml.attributes.length; j++) {
            var attribute = xml.attributes.item(j);
            obj["@attributes"][attribute.nodeName] = attribute.nodeValue;
        }
    }
} else if (xml.nodeType == 3) { // text
    obj = xml.nodeValue;
}

// do children
if (xml.hasChildNodes()) {
    for(var i = 0; i < xml.childNodes.length; i++) {
        var item = xml.childNodes.item(i);
        var nodeName = item.nodeName;
        if (typeof(obj[nodeName]) == "undefined") {
            obj[nodeName] = xmlToJson(item);
        } else {
            if (typeof(obj[nodeName].push) == "undefined") {
                var old = obj[nodeName];
                obj[nodeName] = [];
                obj[nodeName].push(old);
            }
            obj[nodeName].push(xmlToJson(item));
        }
    }
    }
    return obj;
};
```

Source: http://davidwalsh.name/convert-xml-json

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're requesting a RSS feed. Feeds always have a `title` element, `description` element and `link` element as XML nodes and not as (JSON) objects.

To get xml elements back you need to use a XML parser function. At the moment you treat the data as if it's JSON. You try to retrieve `message` or `description` using `data.message` and `data.description` as if it's a property. In reality those are xml nodes.

To get the content of the feed from the nodes you can traverse *xml* in *jQuery* in almost the same manner as you traverse *dom nodes*. In the function below I converted the data from the returned xml file to a jQuery object using `$xml = $( result )`.

In jQuery

```
function RequestService() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://www.brazilmachinery.com/Arquivos/RSS/pt-BR/12.xml",
        data: "",
        dataType: "xml",
        error: function(data) { FailureCallBack(data); }
    }).done(function(data) { SucessCallback(data);});
}

function SucessCallback(result) {
    $xml = $( result );
    $title = $xml.find( "item" ).each(function(){
        $('p').append('Resultado: ' + $(this).find("title").text() + ' <br /> Descrição: ' + $(this).find("description").text());
    });


}
```

Also I replaced the `success` property with the newer done functionality. It now finds all items within the RSS feed and iterates over them. Appending the data to the `p`-element.

A RSS-xml-document has the following basic structure

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rss version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <title>
            Title
        </title>
        <link>
            http://www.example.com
        </link>
        <item>
            <title>Item title</title>
            <link>www.example.com/item</link>
            <description>
                item description here.
            </description>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```